# Prove the convergence of $\int_{0}^{1}(\ln(x))^2\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Prove the convergence of $\int_{0}^{1}(\ln(x))^2\,{\rm d}x$

I know from plugging into a calculator that this is $2$. I'm just not sure how to show this. I want to come up with a function greater than it that forces to converge, but I'm not sure that will work.

Answer (score 2):

Your thought that there might be a function such that $ \ f(x) \ > \ (\ln x)^2 \ $ on $ \ (0 \ , \ 1] \ $ for which $ \ \int_0^1 \ f(x) \ \ dx \ $ converges is a reasonable idea, but using integral comparison is only helpful if we can show easily that our choice of function in fact converges.

It would be really nice, for example, if we could show that $ \ (\ln x)^2 \ < \ \frac{1}{x^p} $ for $ \ 0 \ < \ p \ < \ 1 \ $ , since we know that $ \ \int_0^1 \ \frac{1}{x^p} \ \ dx \ $ converges for those values of $ \ p \ $ . Unfortunately, this doesn't work out for just anything in that interval: for $ \ p \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ $ , the two curves intersect in $ \ (0 \ , \ 1] \ $ , with the desired inequality only being true for $ \ \approx 0.24 \ < \ x \ \le \ 1 \ $  .

However, if we solve for the intersection point(s) using $ \ (\ln x)^2 \ = \ x^{-p} \ $ , we find (with the aid of the Lambert W-function) that there are no intersection points in $ \ (0 \ , \ 1] \ $ for $ \ \frac{2}{e} \ < \ p \ < \ 1 \ $ . So it *is* possible to choose values of $ \ p \ $ that will give us the convergent integrals we seek.  Thus, we have, for instance,

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^{3/4}} \ \ dx \ \ > \ \ \int_0^1 (\ln x)^2 \ \ dx $$

convergent with  $  x^{-3/4} \ > \  (\ln x)^2 \ $ over the interval of integration.

But it *is* faster to just do the integration-by-parts...

Answer (score 1):

Let us approach this problem by evaluating the improper integral. See below:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\ln^{2}\left(x\right)dx$$
$$\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{a}^{1}\ln^{2}\left(x\right)dx$$

Now use integration by parts to evaluate the integral; the result is displayed below:
$$\lim_{a\to 0}\left[x\ln^{2}(x) - 2x\ln(x) + 2\right]_{a}^{1}$$

Using L'Hopital's Theorem on the limit expression when $a$ approaches $0,$ we find the limit to be
$$\left[\left(0 - 0 + 2\right) - \left(0\right)\right],$$
which we find equals $2.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int _0^1\ln ^2\left(x\right)dx$$
Apply Integration By Parts:

$\color{green}{u=\ln ^2\left(x\right),\:u'=\frac{2\ln \left(x\right)}{x},\:\:v'=1,\:\:v=x}$
$$=\ln ^2\left(x\right)x-\int \frac{2\ln \left(x\right)}{x}xdx=x\ln ^2\left(x\right)-\int \:2\ln \left(x\right)dx$$
Then:

$\int \:2\ln \left(x\right)dx=2\left(x\ln \left(x\right)-x\right)$(solved by parts)

So:
$$=x\ln ^2\left(x\right)-2\left(x\ln \left(x\right)-x\right)=x\ln ^2\left(x\right)-2\left(x\ln \left(x\right)-x\right)$$
$$=x\ln ^2\left(x\right)-2\left(x\ln \left(x\right)-x\right)+C$$
$$\int _0^1\ln ^2\left(x\right)dx=\color{red}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

To find the value of the integral you need to apply integration by parts twice.

The first time you must let $u=(\ln(x))^2)$ and $\frac {dv}{dx}=1$

The second time you must let $u=\ln(x)$ and $\frac {dv}{dx}=2$

Proving that it will converge is a bit trickier...